# creating dataframe on the basis of R-squared value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below,

df1 =

```
Index   bins  one         two         three       four
a       1     0.760207    0.313230    1.257121    3.777180
b       2     0.920607    0.350345    -0.424963   0.032379
c       3     -0.975032   0.580298    1.819454    -0.807784
d       4     -0.886256   0.656349    0.306178    1.172622
e       5     0.512182    0.362790    1.066892    0.250835
```

I want to get a dataframe that simply gives the r-squared value of columns one, two, three, four with column bins. So that the dataframe that I want looks like below.

df2 =

```
columns     r-square_with_bins
one         0.25
two         0.7
three       0.35
four        0.01
five        0.112
```

The r-squared values I have written here are not exact and for understanding the dataframe structure only.
And in the real dataset, there are more than 200 columns with the first column being 'bins'.
But the problem is the same as this one.

need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.stats.linregress()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) to find the `rvalue` and then square it for R².

Start by importing the module:

```
import scipy.stats
```

Then, for example, to calculate R² with `'bins'` for column `'one'`:

```
scipy.stats.linregress(df1[['bins', 'one']].to_numpy()).rvalue ** 2
```

Results in 0.15589578141321594 to me.

In order to do that with all columns (except for `'bins'`, which is the first column), just do each calculation in a `for` loop (using a list comprehension, for example.)

This will create a new DataFrame `df2` like the one you described:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'columns': df1.columns[1:],
    'r-square_with_bins': [
        scipy.stats.linregress(df1[['bins', col]].to_numpy()).rvalue ** 2
        for col in df1.columns[1:]
    ]
})
```

Which produces the following DataFrame:

```
         r-square_with_bins
columns                    
one                0.155896
two                0.171381
three              0.004014
four               0.280958
```